# Pipes `run` with State

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have a producer:

`p :: Producer Message IO r`.

I can process all messages using:

`runEffect $ for p processMessage`

where

`processMessage :: Message -> Effect IO ()`.

How can I implement stateful processing using something like:

`processMessage :: Message -> Effect (StateT MyState IO) ()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Modify your producer to be agnostic to the monad it's running in
2. Your `processMessage` is fine
3. The `runEffect` returns `StateT MyState IO ()`, you need to evaluate it

Longer answer with a dummy example:

Your producer is locked into the `IO` monad, you need to modify it to be either in `MonadIO m` or in the explicit state monad.

```hs
import Control.Monad.State
import Pipes

type Message = Int

p :: MonadIO m => Producer Message m ()
p = each [1..10]
```

The signature of your `processMessage` is already fine. I'm following your signature and adding some simple logic to exercise the IO and State functionality

```hs
processMessage :: Message -> Effect (StateT MyState IO) ()
processMessage msg = do
  modify (+ msg)
  liftIO (print msg)
```

Then the final step. `runEffect :: Monad m => Effect m r -> m r`, if you substitute the `m` with a concrete type, this ends up being `runEffect :: Effect (StateT MyState IO) () -> StateT MyState IO ()`, meaning that you'll be left with the state monad which still needs to be executed. There's three variants for executing the state monad, `runStateT`, `evalStateT` and `execStateT`. I chose `execStateT :: StateT MyState IO () -> IO MyState` variant in this example, but choose whichever you need in your case.

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  st <- execStateT (runEffect $ for p processMessage) 0
  putStrLn $ "End state: " <> show st
```